# Getting memory usage by an object in java

Tags: java

I need memory used by an object on run time for some analysis purpose. I am using netbeans 5.1 which doesn't support profiling and I can't use later version of netbeans due to project compatibility. Please suggest some alternative for this with detailed explanation.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Answer (score 0):

This is just for an understanding of how it works:

For example if you have a class like:

```
public class A{
    int i;
    long l;
    double a[]=new double[N];
   }
```

The memory cost will be as follows:

1) Object Overhead : 16 bytes

2) for int **i** : 4 bytes

3) for long **l**: 8 bytes

4) For array of type double **a** : 8*N(8 bytes for double*number of elements in the array)+24 bytes overhead+8 bytes reference to the array

5) Now you add padding bytes so that the total sum of bytes is divisible by 8.
And similar goes for other primitives also.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution: Convert Object to ByteArrray and get the length of the array. It should work in older java versions too.

```
 import java.io.*;  

    class ObjectData implements Serializable{
        private int id=1;;
        private String name="sunrise76";
        private String city = "Newyork";
        private int dimensitons[] = {20,45,789}; 
    }

    public class ObjectSize{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            try{
            ObjectData data = new ObjectData();
            ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
            oos.writeObject(data);
            System.out.println("Size:"+b.toByteArray().length);
            }catch(Exception err){
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Output from the program for "java ObjectSize"
>
> Size:156